# Liberty Server error when running on the RESTful web-service on server

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-mq, websphere-liberty

I am newer on the IBM websphere mq, when I started to run the server in eclipse. it always has the following error like A feature definition could not be found for mdb-3.2 or wmqjmsclient-2.0

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.9/wlp-1.0.12.cl50920160227-1523) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_77-b03 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.9/lafiles/en.html
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for mdb-3.2
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for wmqjmsclient-2.0
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[err] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.ibm.pong.common.config.Config).
[err] log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[err] log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have defined them in the server.xml

```
<featureManager>
        <feature>jsp-2.3</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
        <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>

        <feature>ejbLite-3.2</feature>
        <feature>distributedMap-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
        <feature>mdb-3.2</feature>
        <feature>wmqJmsClient-2.0</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
```

Answer (score 1):

JDBC 4.0 is a Java EE 6 feature, and Liberty 8.5.5.9 comes with Java EE 7 features installed by default (I suspect you will find that JDBC 4.1 is already in the package you have downloaded). If you need to use JDBC 4.0, you can install it in to Liberty alongside 4.1, and select which one to use in your server.xml. Have a look at wasdev.net for how to install additional features, the page for JDBC 4.0 is [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.jdbc-4.0)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, right, I can find JDBC 4.1, but how can I enable on wmqjmsclient-2.0?  [ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for wmqjmsclient-2.0

Comment: wmqjmsclient-2.0 is not included in any of the downloadable liberty packages, it will always need to be installed separately. The relevant feature page on wasdev.net [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/features-com.ibm.websphere.appserver.wmqJmsClient-2.0) has instructions

Comment: thanks a lot, your information is very useful, I just installed it separately, and then no this error now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to summarize the posts and comments.

So if you downloaded WLP Java EE7 or Java EE 7 Web Profile you only are getting features required by the Java EE 7 spec. The jdbc-4.0 is from Java EE 6 and jdbc-4.1 is from Java EE 7. So you either need to switch to jdbc-4.1 (recommended) or install jdbc-4.0 feature.

To list features that are available issue the following command:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\wlp\bin>productInfo.bat featureInfo
```

You can install additional features using `installUtility` command , either one by one, or installing the bundle.

To have all the features from the Java EE 6, Java EE 7 and WebSphere specific like for example MQ client, issue the following:

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\wlp\bin>installUtility install baseBundle
```

You can see all the features contained in the bundle here [Liberty features in the bundles](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSCKBL_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_feat.html)